# Student's Result program in Java

Tags: java

```
import java.io.DataInputstream;
class Student
{
int roll;
void getdata(int r)
 {
 roll=r;
 }
void putroll()
 {
 System.out.println("The roll number is: "+roll);
 }
}

class Test extends Student
{
int sub1,sub2;
void getmarks(int a, int b)
 {
 sub1=a;
 sub2=b;
 }
void putmarks()
 {
 System.out.println("Marks 1= "+ sub1 + "\n Marks 2= "+sub2);
 }

interface Sport
{
float spt=6.0f;
void putspt(float num);
}


class Result extends Test implements Sport
{
float total;
float n;
public void putspt(float num)
 {
 x=num;
 if(x>6 && x<=10)
 System.out.println("Sport= "+x);
 else
 System.out.println("Sport= "+spt);
 }
void display()
 {
 if(x>6 && x<=10)
 total=sub1+sub2+x;
 else
 total=sub1+sub2+spt;
 putroll();
 putmarks();
 if(x>6 && x<=10)
 putspt(x);
 else
 putspt(spt);
 System.out.println("Total marks= "+total);
 }
}


class Student_Test
{
public static void main(String a[]) throws Exception
 {
 DataInputStream ds = new DataInputStream(System.in);
 int a,b,c;
 float d;
 try
  {
  int t;
  System.out.println("\nEnter total no. of Students:");
  t=Integer.parseInt(ds.readLine());
  for(int i=1;i<=t;i++)
   {
    System.out.println("Enter Roll no.:");
    a=Integer.parseInt(ds.readLine());
    System.out.println("Enter the marks of two subjects:");
    b=Integer.parseInt(ds.readLine());
    c=Integer.parseInt(ds.readLine());
    System.out.println("Enter Sports marks:");
    d=Integer.parseInt(ds.readLine());
    Result r=new Result();
    r.getroll(a);
    r.getmarks(b,c);
    r.putspt(d);
    r.display();
   }
  }
  catch(Exception e)
    {
    System.out.println("ERROR");
    }
 }
}
```

I am getting the following error at compilation time:

Student.java:97: reached end of file while parsing
}->

P.S: 97th line is the last line of the program

**Can somebody help me to solve this error??**

Comment: I've got the feeling that all the five types are in the same file (because of the single `import` statement). The Java compiler requires each class to be in a separate file, might that be the problem?

Comment: @cecil: Uh, no it doesn't.  You can have as many private classes in one file as you want, just one public class, and the public class has to have the same name as the file.  Also, you can have as many nested inner classes as you want.

Answer (score 9):

You have missed the closing brace on class `Test`, before `interface Sport`.

As a side note, if you format (and specifically indent) your source code properly, you won't have such problems in the future.

Comment: +1 for the side note.  (When I was an undergraduate, solutions were marked down heavily if they were not properly commented and indented.)

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a } to close your Test class (about halfway in)

Answer (score 1):

The `Test` class doesn't have a closing curly brace.

Comment: oops!
yeah that brace was missing..but now i am getting 17 errors..
plz run the code..

Comment: @compgeek: how about reading the compiler errors and trying to figure it out yourself? I know the errors are somewhat cryptic when you're new, but you'll figure it out. :) everyone else here has.

Answer (score 1):

Class Test is missing a:

```
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the closing brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
package test3;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class switchandifpr {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int m ,  p;
        System.out.println("Enter Total Marke");
        Scanner en=new Scanner(System.in);
        m=en.nextInt();
        en.close();
        p=m/7;
        System.out.println("Per Is " +p);
        if(p>=35 && p <= 45)
        {
            System.out.println("PassClass");
        }
        else if(p>=45 && p <= 55){
            System.out.println("Second class");
        }

        else if(p>=55 && p <= 70){
            System.out.println("Firts Class");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Fail");
        }
    }
}
```